# How to display azure app service's web server log on Azure log Analytics?

Tags: azure, logging, cloud, azure-web-app-service, log-analysis

I have an api application hosted on azure App services. For the web server log (iis logs) I've turned on web server logging from Azure portal. Look at the screenshot below.
[image: Azure diagnostics logs settings for web server]

For storing web server logging

Server Logs are allowed to be stored on the Azure blob containers only. As per the configuration the logs are stored on blob container as expected. Now I want to use these logs to be displayed on Azure Log Analytics.

I've the following storage configurations on Log Analytics in Azure Web portal.
[image]

On Log Analytics explorer I can view logs from all other sources except the web server (iis logs). What I'm missing here?

Comment: is it something to do with the log level that you configure in the data sources menu. just guessing ..

Comment: I don't think so :(

Comment: If it is still actual: if portal configuration is all right, most likely something wrong with trace listener and level configuration or logging itself.

Comment: i want to view server logs (API logs), did you find any solution ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Verified with App Services team](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/11824) that **Log Analytics** is only supported at the **IaaS** (VM) level, *not* at **PaaS** (App Service) level.

Hopefully we can get this on their roadmap soon - for now you have to manually ingest this data into an external log management tool (*[Splunk](https://www.splunk.com/), [Sumo Logic](https://www.sumologic.com/), [Azure Data Explorer](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/data-explorer/)*).

#### Update 12/02/2019

**Azure App Service** has announced a [Public Preview for IIS App Log integration with Azure Log Analytics](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/new-app-service-integration-with-azure-monitor-preview/).

Comment: Very useful. Thank you, and great to hear it from a MSFTer. Becuase I could not find it I assumed I had missed something, as it seems such an obvious omission. Also good to to seen your list of other tools.

Comment: I don't really understand why this should not be supported? I mean its logfiles? Does it matter where they come from? So frustrating to not be able to easily create alerts and stuff based on the raw http logs.

Comment: Based on an announcement on the 4th Nov, this is now available in preview, https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/new-app-service-integration-with-azure-monitor-preview/.

Comment: @Kieron - [confirming the feature is now in preview](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/11824#issuecomment-561042194) => great catch!

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on the prior answer, under the `Diagnostic settings (preview)` pane you can now integrate multiple logs to Azure via `Add diagnostics setting`, this can store:

- AppServiceAntivirusScanAuditLogs
- AppServiceHTTPLogs
- AppServiceConsoleLogs
- AppServiceAppLogs
- AppServiceFileAuditLogs
- AppServiceAuditLogs
- AppServiceIPSecAuditLogs
- AppServicePlatformLogs
- AllMetrics

You can send them to:

- **Log Analytics workspace**
- Archive to storage account
- Stream to event hub
- Send to partner solution

Additionally, Application Insights is migrating to be backed by Log Analytics so we are getting close to fully integrated platform for metrics and logs