# Azure Log Analytics and Azure App Service Access Logs, can they be connected?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-storage

I think the answer is yes, but I cannot find any definitive answer. I did find this, but...

[How to display azure app service's web server log on Azure log Analytics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38097126/how-to-display-azure-app-services-web-server-log-on-azure-log-analytics)

Can this be achieved and if so how? Do I have to create an Event Hub ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posted the answer to your [linked SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52569119/175679). This is not currently possible unless you manually setup [Azure Data Explorer](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/data-explorer/). Trying to get his much needed feature on their radar - it's immensely valuable for diagnostic troubleshooting, traffic analysis, as well as security audits.

Comment: Very useful. Thank you, and great to hear it from a MSFTer. Becuase I could not find it I assumed I had missed something, as it seems such an obvious omission. Also good to to seen your list of other tools. Also thank for raising it on the MS forum

Comment: I have seen Azure Data Lakes being use to access this data, see: https://vincentlauzon.com/2016/01/24/analyzing-web-logs-with-azure-data-lake-analytics-adla/