# Can we query blog storage log in Azure Monitor Logs?

Tags: azure-log-analytics, azure-monitoring

My application stores logs in blog storage as that is the setting in App Service. My understanding is there are IIS logs in app service and they go to the blob storage as well.
A)[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/data-collection) it is mentioned that "All log data in Azure Monitor is retrieved using a log query written with the Kusto query language"

B) But [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/de-de/blog/query-azure-storage-analytics-logs-in-azure-log-analytics/) it is mentioned that we need to do it manually:

1. Create workspace
2. Convert storage log to Json
3. Post logs to workspace
4. And only now you can query

Which one is true?

- A: Do nothing and query logs from storage explorer
- B: Migrate manually

Imagine if A is true then how do I know which table or DB shown on the explorer has the data from blog storage. And how do I differentiate between IIS logs?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Log Analytics can read the logs for the following services that write diagnostics to table storage or IIS logs written to blob storage:

- Service Fabric Clusters
- Virtual Machines
- Web/Worker Roles

However IIS logs from Azure Websites are not currently supported as out of box solution.
[Documentation Reference.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/azure-storage-iis-table)

You have to either perform it manual or automate the process to read from storage blob and send it to either Log Analytics/Application Insights as per your requirement.

Other related SO thread on same issue -

[Azure Log Analytics and Azure App Service Access Logs, can they be connected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52557398/azure-log-analytics-and-azure-app-service-access-logs-can-they-be-connected/52569162#52569162)

[How to display azure app services web server log on Azure Log Analytics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38097126/how-to-display-azure-app-services-web-server-log-on-azure-log-analytics/52569119#52569119)

You can always share your feedback and up vote the feature request [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps/suggestions/33864499-support-sending-web-server-logs-to-oms-log-analyti).

Hope it helps.