# Play console: Where can I find a list of the devices that my app is running on?

Tags: google-play-console

I am looking for a way to export the list of devices on that my Android app is currently installed.

Is this possible and if yes, how?

Comment: your question is not related to programming, therefore it is off-topic here

Comment: This is a question that some programmers need to know. For example, when considering adding features to an app, they need to know how many users are running on devices that are too slow for that feature. This question is just one of probably thousands of questions about services used by programmers ([random example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38097126/145173)).

Answer (score 31, accepted):

On play, go to your app page. On the left sidebar, select Statistics.

2. Open "Add a new metric, or edit an existing one" dropdown
3. Select Devices > Install Base > all devices
4. Below in "View by", select "Device" from dropdown, deselect all filters, then click "+ Device" and select "All devices"
5. Select Export Report > Export change analysis

That's it, you'll have a list of *active devices* running your app.

Comment: This option doesn't let you select more than 5 devices

Comment: @mmarquezvacas which option does?

Comment: @mmarquezvacas now it lets you select up to 10.

Comment: How can we get all devices at once? even select all is selected it's not working it seems. There is a bug while selecting the checkbox too.