# How to get list devices model installed my app android?

Tags: android, react-native, google-play-console

I have an app android was published to CH play.

Now i want to get top 10 device model are using my app.

Is there anyway to do that?
Can i find out it in Google Play Console?

many tks

Comment: use `os.Build.Model` and post it to back-end

Comment: if do that,i can't get old data

Comment: there is Statistics tab on the left in Google Play Console, you can find in there some info about models

Comment: @snachmsm really? i'm seeing that it only show number devices

Comment: really, I've just set some chart with models on my console, just look for proper options, they are there

Comment: @snachmsm , please give me an image , or tell me more detail

Comment: @snachmsm i find out it, tks so much !

Answer (score 0):

after research i know that Google Play Console able show Device Name Installed my App
[Play console: Where can I find a list of the devices that my app is running on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54606812/play-console-where-can-i-find-a-list-of-the-devices-that-my-app-is-running-on)
Answer of this Question helped me.
And this is Result
[link image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJZML.png)