# Querying IIS logs from blob using Azure Log Analytics (formerly OMS)

Tags: azure, logging, azure-log-analytics, kql

I am attempting to use Azure Log analytics to query IIS logs that sit in four separate storage accounts (based on region) that are generated from our WebApps. Is this possible? I'm only seeing azure activity logs on my queries - I'm very new to log analytics, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hello, if the answer is helpful, could you please help mark it as answer? it would be helpful for others. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct way for this, you can take a look at this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38097126/how-to-display-azure-app-services-web-server-log-on-azure-log-analytics/52569119#52569119) and it mentions:

**Log Analytics is only supported at the IaaS (VM) level, not at PaaS (App Service) level.**

If you want to do that, you can manually set up a way which sends the logs from blob storage to Log analytics, following this [tutorial](https://azure.microsoft.com/fr-fr/blog/query-azure-storage-analytics-logs-in-azure-log-analytics/)(It's a little hard to do that).

As well, you can also upvote on this [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps/suggestions/33864499-support-sending-web-server-logs-to-oms-log-analyti).

Comment: I'm not quite sure if I understand this answer; there are logs in my storage account sitting in a blob container. Is log analytics not able to get to this level to aggregate and analyze this data?

Comment: @CianEstella, It's just not available for the iis logs(from azure web app) stored in azure storage.